# Is there a good practice in Angular.js to pass data through URL?

Tags: angularjs, url

I have a page and tabs on it, I want each tab to to have a URL (I use angular UI to switch tabs)

What would be the best way to include the tab ID in the url? I trie the simplest  - using `#` - but it seems angular has routing issues using hash locations.

Answer (score 1):

See on angular-route-segment ([http://angular-route-segment.com](http://angular-route-segment.com/));
Click in [demo](http://angular-route-segment.com/src/example/#/section1) on Item 1 or Item2 and see tabs. 
Or use ui-router.